# Mistake in published paper about magnetic levitation?

Tags: voltage, current, electromagnetism, control

As I was reading through this paper: [Nonlinear Model & Controller Design for Magnetic Levitation System](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d25a/42958aa11bbd30171a8e496f412a45d22b1f.pdf), I stumbled cross section 3.3 which I could not follow.

Summarizing section **3.3 Non Linear Model**.

The magnetic levitation system can be described in terms of the following equations.

[image]

Equation (2) indicates that `L(x)` is a nonlinear function
of the ball position `x`. Therefore we need to approximate the inductance for the MLS. The authors chose the following approximation:

[image]

They then proceeded to substitute into equation 2.

[image]

**Should it be 2*C or simply C in Eq.5?**

How did they end up with equation 5, from equation 2? I am having trouble understanding the origins of the negative sign (which I am sure that there is an explanation to) in the second equation of the image above, but also where the 2 in front of `C` has gone.

Is there a mistake here, or am I missing something? Can someone help me with the math and show how this was worked out?

Comment: Is it only the factor 2 you're concerned about, or is it also something else?

Comment: My main concern is the factor 2. However I have also not been able to understand how the negative sign came to be, in the second equation of the third image.

Comment: The sign is from \$\frac{d(1/x)}{dt} = \frac{-1}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}\$.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thanks @SvenB, missed the negative sign in my calculation.

Comment: But it is a bit confusing to me though. Is it \$\frac{d}{dt}\left(L(x)i\right)\$ or \$\frac{d}{dt}\left(L(x)\right)\cdot i\$? In either case, something would have gone wrong after that too.

Comment: I am assuming it is the latter, due to how the first equation of the third image is depicted.

Comment: I don't think so because the second line contains \$\frac{di}{dt}\$. However, they then decided to write \$L\frac{di}{dt}\$ instead of \$L(x)\frac{di}{dt}\$ to add some confusion, and then failed to make a simple substitution.
This paper lacks professionalism and should be treated as such. Don't spend too much time on it.