# Comparing responses for linear and non-linear system in Simulink

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, matlab, simulink

I am going through and reviewing this [unprofessional](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/406984/mistake-in-published-paper-about-magnetic-levitation) (I highlight a potential mistake in Section3.4) paper: [Nonlinear Model & Controller Design for Magnetic Levitation System](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d25a/42958aa11bbd30171a8e496f412a45d22b1f.pdf)

Specifically, I am trying to compare the responses of the linear and non-linear model in Simulink, using the parameters provided in Table 1 of that same paper. I am to comment on any discrepancies.

I am having trouble comparing responses, since they are totally different from each other.I suspect that I may have a mistake/misunderstanding when it comes to plotting the non-linear model. A very brief summary of the paper follows.

---

**System**

[image]

**Non-Linear Vector Format**

[image]

**Linear Model**

[image]

---

**Comparing Responses - Working**

For the **non-linear model** I used a [MATLAB function block](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-an-example-model-that-uses-a-matlab-function-block.html), with the following script:

```
function y = fcn(u)

    % define your constants
    g = 9.81;
    m = 0.05;
    R = 1;
    L = 0.01;
    C = 0.0001; 
    x1 = 0.012;
    x2 = 0;
    x3 = 0.84;


% nonlinear set of equations
x = [x2; g-((C/m)*(x3/x1)^2); -((R/L)*x3 + (((2*C)/L)*(((x2*x3)/((x1)^2)))))] + [0;0;1/L]*u;

y = x';
```

I then gave a step input to the system and got the following result. Yellow is the step input, green is the output.

[image]

---

Next, I proceeded with the **linear model**. I placed the matrices `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` inside a [state space block.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/statespace.html)

[image]

To get the numbers you see above, I replaced the constants with the parameters given in the paper. I got the following output.

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

As can be seen, both responses are completely different, and I am unsure about what discrepancies I should comment about. **Are my non-linear and linear model implementations correct?** I can add further details or workings if required.

**Simulink build**

[image]

**Parameters**:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Re-calculate the bottom line of your \$A\$ matrix.

Comment: I am getting: `[0 116.66 -100]`

Comment: Value seems correct...

Comment: A quick scan of your results tells me that (1) the non-linear model does't seem to be representing any dynamics, and (2) the linear model is not converging. Have you checked the eigenvalues of your linear state matrix?

Comment: I meant, recalculate the bottom line of your *symbolic representation* of your \$A\$ matrix.  It is in error.  (I'm assuming this is homework, or answers would be spewing forth).

Comment: @TimWescott, I'm not sure where the mistake lies. I edited code for the non-linear model, but the symbolic representation of the A matrix (linear model) is given directly in the paper. I replaced the parameters with the values in the tables and got the same answer once again. There is however, a mistake in the second row of the A matrix as I pointed out in the linked question.

Comment: @EdgarBrown, no, I have yet to check the eigenvalues of the linear matrix. This was given in the paper (with a mistake in the second row), and I replaced the parameters with the values from Table 1 of the paper.

Comment: how do you know they are comparable?

Comment: I am tasked to comment on any discrepancies between the two, thus I am assuming that they can be compared.

Comment: \$\frac{d}{dx_3}\frac{x_2 x_3}{x_1^2} = \frac{x_2}{x_1^2}\$.  This is not reflected in the linearized model.  Perhaps the paper is in error?

Comment: @TimWescott, actually it is represented. We are left with `-R/L`, since `x2 = 0`

Comment: I looked over your plots again.  If you carefully inspect the \$\dot x_2\$ line of the nonlinear equation, then you see that if you start with a system in steady state, with acceleration (\$\dot x_2\$) zero, any reduction in position (\$x_1\$) makes the acceleration negative, and any increase in position makes the acceleration positive.  This matches intuition, but it doesn't match your simulation.  I'd look there, and see if you can find a problem.

Comment: @TimWescott, thanks for the suggestion. Will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ah HA!**.  You used a Matlab nonlinear function block, but you're misunderstanding the system equation.  The function \$\dot{\vec x} = f(\vec x, u)\$ is coughing up the **derivative** of \$\vec x\$, not \$\vec x\$ itself.  You need to have a function block that *just* finds \$\dot{\vec x}\$ from \$\vec x\$ and \$u\$, then feeds it to an integrator (Simulink should be able to integrate a vector just fine) and feeds the \$\vec x\$ back to the block, and extracts \$y\$ from it.

Here's a block diagram of what you want to achieve (sorry for the crappy picture).  I can't remember my Simulink well enough to say exactly how to do it -- I suspect you can make a multi-input, multi-output block, but if you can't you can make a concatinated input vector with x and u, and concatenate y and x-dot in the output, and use muxing and demuxing to get the data in and out.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The diagram is great, helped me understand what you meant. However, could you expand a little on how you came to the conclusion that the function is coughing up the derivative of x and not x itself?

Comment: Because the vector on the left side is \$[ \dot x_1 \dot x_2 \dot x_3 ]^T \$, not \$[ x_1 x_2 x_3 ]^T \$.  A dot over a variable denotes its time derivative.